# In express.js why does code still execute after return statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

In node js, I have the following piece of code

```
const express = require('express');
const pool = require('../db');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const router = express.Router();
const { registerValidation } = require('../validation')
const { sendEmail } = require('./sendEmail')

router.post("/", async(req, res) => {
  // LETS VALIDATE THE DATA BEFORE MAKE A USER and it comes from validation.js file
    const { error } = registerValidation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  // If the user already exists
  pool.query("select email from users where email='"+req.body.email+"'", function(err, data){
    if(data.rows.length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).send("This email already exists");
    }
  })

  // Hash password
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

  try{
      const { name, username, email, verified, token, recieveEmail, gender } = req.body;        
      const newUser = await pool.query("INSERT INTO users (name, username, email, verified, token, password, recieveEmail, gender) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING *", 
      [name, username, email, verified, token, hashedPassword, recieveEmail, gender]);

      const { error } = sendEmail(req.body.email);
      if (!error){
        return res.status(400).send("Email could not be sent");
      }
      res.json(newUser.rows);
  }catch(err){
      console.error(err.message)
  }
})

module.exports = router;
```

If I try with a duplicate email id which is already exist in the users table, it shows the error message **This email already exists** and at the same time it inserts the data into the users table, send email to the given email address. It means that the code is still executed after the return statement.

I was wondering why it does not stop working when it found the return statement?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `pool.query()` requires a callback because it is an asynchronous operation. You need to move all the remaining code *inside* the callback function so it runs *after* the query has finished. (You can also rewrite your `db.js` file so it returns a Promise which resolves to the query result and `await` the query call.)

Comment: dont do `"select email from users where email='"+req.body.email+"'"`, its opening yourself upt to SQL injection, prepared querys are built in.. do `"select email from users where email=?` and then `pool.query("...", [req.body.email], func`

Comment: **TL;DR**: the `return` statement is inside a callback function, not in the route handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in question is inside [a callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) passed to `pool.query()`. This means that code execution, when it reaches `pool.query()`, *immediately continues execution*, leading to the behavior you're seeing.

When the callback returns, it's simply ending execution of the callback itself, and is run independently of the main sequence of your code at that point.

```js
pool.query("select email from users where email='" + req.body.email + "'", 
  // Callback vvvv
  function(err, data) {
    if (data.rows.length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).send("This email already exists");
    }
  }
);
```

---

<sub>NOTE: As mentioned elsewhere, the code here is a pretty huge security vulnerability, since you're directly executing incoming, potentially unsafe, request data in a call to your database. It's called a [SQL injection attack](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection), and you should absolutely address it if you plan on deploying this code.</sub>

Comment: email field; `';DROP TABLE users;--`